# Searching For Elements With Multiple Matches

Tags: c++, stl

I have a `vector` of Key-Value pairs, where each Key-Value pair is also tagged with an Entry Type code.  The possible Entry Type codes are:

```
enum Type
{
  tData = 0,
  tSeqBegin = 1,  // the beginning of a sequence
  tSeqEnd = 2     // the end of a sequence
};
```

So the Key-Value pair itself looks like this:

```
struct KeyVal
{
  int key_;
  string val_;  
  Type type_;
};
```

Within the vector are sub-arrays of additional Key-Value pairs.  These sub-arrays are called 'sequences'.  Sequences can be nested to any level.  So sequences can themselves have (optional) sub-sequences of varying lengths.  The combination of a Key and `Type` is unique within a sequence *element*.  That is, within a single sequence element there can only be one `269` data row, but other sequence elements can have their own `269` data rows.

Here is a graphical representation of some sample data, grossly oversimplified (If the 'Type' column is blank, it is of type `tData`):

```
Row#            Type            Key     Value      
----            -------------   -----   --------   
1                               35      "W"
2                               1181    "IBM"
3               tSeqBegin       268     "3"
4                               269     "0"
5                               270     "160.3"
6               tSeqEnd         0 
7                               269     "0"
8                               290     "0"
9               tSeqBegin       453     "1"      <-- subsequence
10              tSeqEnd         0                <-- end of subsequence
11              tSeqEnd         0
12                              269     "0"
13                              290     "1"
14                              270     "160.4"
15              tSeqEnd         0 
16                              1759    "ABC"
```

[EDIT:  A note on the above.  There is one `tSeqBegin` that marks the beginning of the whole sequence.  The end of each sequence *element* is marked by a `tSeqEnd`.  But there is no special `tSeqEnd` that also marks the end of the whole sequence.  So for a sequence you will see 1 `tSeqBegin` and `n` `tSeqEnd`s, where `n` is the number of elements within the sequence.

Another note, in the above sequence beginning at row #3 and ending at row #15, there is one subsequence in the 2nd element (rows 7-11).  The subsequence is empty, and occupies rows 9 and 10.]

What I'm trying to do is find a sequence element which has *multiple* Key-Value matches to certain criteria.  For example, suppose I want to find the sequence element that has both `269="0"` *and* `290="0"`.  In this case, it should not find element #0 (starting at row 3) because that element doesn't have a `290=...` row at all.  It should find the element starting at row #7 instead.  Ultimately I will extract other fields from this element, but that's beyond the scope of this problem, so I haven't included that data above.

I can't use `std::find_if()` because `find_if()` will evaluate each row individually, not the whole sequence element as a unit.  So I can't construct a functor that evaluates something like `if 269=="0" &&* 290=="0"` because no single row will ever evaluate this to `true`.

I had thought to implement my own `find_sequence_element(...)` function.  But this would involve some fairly complex logic.  First I would have to identify the `begin()` and `end()` of the entire sequence, noting where each element `begin()`'s and `end()`'s.  Then I would have to construct some kind of evaluation structure that I could string together like this psudocode:

`Condition cond = KeyValueMatch(269, "0") + KeyValueMatch(290, "0");`

But this is also complex.  I can't just construct a `find_sequence_element()` that takes exactly 2 parameters, one for the `269` match and another for the `290` match, because I want to use this algorithm for other sequences as well, with more or fewer conditions.

Moreover, it seems like I should be able to use the STL `<algorithm>`'s that already exist.  While I know the STL rather well, I can't figure out a way to use `find_if()` in any straightforward way.

So, finally, here's the question.  If you were faced with the above problem, how would you solve it?  I know the question is vague.  I'm hoping that with some discussion we can narrow the problem domain down until we have an answer.

Some conditions:

- I cannot change the single flat `vector` to a `vector of vectors` or anything of the like.  The reasons for this are complex.
- (Placeholder for more conditions :) )

(If consensus is that this should be CW, I will mark it as such)

Comment: I don't think you can mark it as CW.

Comment: I don't understand the data. Where are rows 9 and 10?  Why do you have `tSeqEnd` with no matching `tSeqBegin`?  Does the example data include any nested subsequences?

Comment: @Steve:  Sorry, edited.  I took the subsequence out of my original post because I thought it added needless complexity to the problem.  I've put it back in.  Do you think I should remove the subsequence and all mention of it?  If so, I can do that.  I don't want to confuse what is already a complex problem.

Comment: @Steve:  re: lack of tSeqBegin.  This is how the data is structured.  There is one `tSeqBegin` for the entire sequence, and each element is delimited by a `tSeqEnd`.  There is no special `tSeqEnd` that also marks the end of the entire sequence.  Its confusing, but it is what it is.

Comment: I think you need that - a recursive structure is harder to process than one that's structured, but at one level.  I still don't understand though, sorry - what rows constitute the parent sequence for rows 9-10?

Comment: @Steve: that would be rows 7-11 I think.

Comment: @Steve:  I've also added a brief note in my post.  Also, unfortunately I don't have control over how the data is structured.  I have to work with it like this.

Comment: Well hello there, FIX protocol. :)

Comment: @Adhemar:  Figured someone would recognize this. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoping I understand your setup correctly, I would proceed as a two-step fashion, nesting search algorithms along the lines of:

```
template<typename It, typename Pr>
It find_sequence_element ( It begin, It end, Pr predicate );
```

except that `Pr` here is a predicate that takes a *sequence* and returns if that sequence matches, yes or no. An example for a single match could be:

```
class HasPair
{
    int key_; string value_;
public:
    Hasmatch ( int key, string value);
    template<typename It>
    bool operator() ( It begin, It end ) const {
        return (std::find_if(begin, end, item_predicate(key_, value_));
    } 
};
```

Where `item_predicate()` is suitable to find the `(key_,value_)` pair in `[begin,end)`.

If you're interested in finding a sequence with two pairs, write a `HasPairs` predicate that invokes `std::find_if` twice, or some more optimized version of a search for two elements.

Comment: +1 this is exactly my initial design.  And it may very well end up being how I roll this out to production.  The reason why I revisited it is because it seems inefficient.  In order to `find_sequence_element` I need to first find the sequence, which involves iterating the whole data set.  Then each `find_if` would iterate all the rows in a single element, looking for an element match.  I would end up ripping over the same pieces of data several times.

Comment: Now, I'm always on the side of not prematurely micro-optimizing, so again this may well be exactly how I do this.  But this is for a stock market server that will process ~3.5 million msgs/second all day long in a single thread. (There will be 31 other threads processing similar traffic).  So it's important to not be wasteful, and I got a little nervous about my design.

Comment: If I understand your search requirements you always need to iterate over all elements at least once, so there are not many ways to go about this. Your sequence predicates will have to be as efficient as possible, though. I explicitly recommend against the double `find_if()` call, but I'd put it in as a first test. I always follow the "correct, beautiful, fast" when I code :-)

Comment: Can you maintain a parallel structure to optimize the location of sequence elements, to be built as you build up the initial vector?  eg. `vector<pair<size_t, size_t>>` where `.first` is the offset and `.second` the length of an element?

Comment: @Steve: I also had a jump-list type thing in mind. However, I would try to store the original list as a `std::list` and have the jump-list contain `vector<pair<list::iterator, list::iterator>>`.

Comment: Yes iterators are better.  John is stuck with the basic `vector` structure, I think.

Comment: And holding `vector::iterator` is asking for trouble :-(

Comment: @Steve, @Andre:  Sorry to pull the wool over your eyes, but in the RW the data isn't really a `vector` -- it is a binary blob( sequential, contiguous, immutable), for which I have already written a custom `const_iterator`  I said I had a `vector` because it is functionally similar, and I didn't want to complicate the question needlessly.

Comment: @Steve: re: " maintain a parallel structure"  I can't build this when the "vector" is first built, but I can do this on the entry to the `find_sequence_element` call.  I thought originally this would be a good starting point for future optimizations.

Comment: That's fine John, now we know you can't change it to `std::list` at least :-) Sounds like a combination of external seq-element index and some type of brute force is the way ahead?

Comment: @John - yes if the container is immutable caching seq-element refs should help

Comment: @Steve, @Andre:  I think this is the way to go.  Which I will get stated with after my coworkers and I go get cheeseburgers. :

Answer (score 3):

I would want to process in an online fashion. Have a type which tracks:

- where the current sequence started
- a count how many requirements have been met so far by the current sequence.

In your example requirements could be represented as a `map<int,string>`. In general they could be a sequence of binary predicates, or something polymorphic if you need to use different functors for different conditions in the same set, and for efficiency progress could be represented as a sequence of booleans, "has this predicate been met yet?"

When you see a `tSeqEnd` you clear the set of met requirements and start again. If your count hits the number of requirements, you're done.

The simplest case is that all predicates specify the key value, and hence only match once. It might look something like:

```
template<typename DataIterator, typename PredIterator>
DataIterator find_matching_sequence(
  DataIterator dataFirst,
  DataIterator dataLast,
  PredIterator predFirst,
  PredIterator predLast) {
    DataIterator sequence_start = dataFirst;
    size_t required = std::distance(predFirst, predLast);
    size_t sofar = 0;
    while (dataFirst != dataLast) {
        if (dataFirst->type == SeqEnd) {
            count = 0;
            ++dataFirst;
            sequence_start = dataFirst;
            continue;
        }
        sofar += std::count(predFirst, predLast, Matches(*dataFirst));
        if (sofar == required) return sequence_start;
        ++dataFirst;
    }
}
```

If the same predicate could match multiple rows in a subsequence, then you can use a `vector<bool>` instead of a count, or possibly a `valarray<bool>`.

To cope with multiply-nested sub-sequences, you actually need a stack of "how am I doing" records, and you might be able to implement that by the function recursively calling itself, and returning early if it sees enough "end" records to know that it has reached the end of its outermost sequence. But I don't really understand that part of the data format.

So no serious use of STL algorithms, unless you want to `std::copy` your initial range into an output iterator that performs the online processing ;-)

Comment: A very straightforward approach, and to me "straightforward" is often == "good" +1

Comment: +1: I also like this because it allows you to specify an arbitrary amount of predicates. Whereas my solution begs for laborious re-writes for additional conditions...